# C# how can I sort a list of file by index using linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Hello I need to sort all the files I have in a folder but I got stuck because I need to sort them by index. I'll give you an example:

My files are formatted like this: dateHoursMinutes_index_nameOfFile.dat

Previous I used `Array.Sort(_myFiles);` to sort them all but now I need to sort them by index, in order.

How can I use linq to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to order list of strings on number substring using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625535/how-to-order-list-of-strings-on-number-substring-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the following sample code:

```
string[] _myFiles = new string[4]
{
    "dateHoursMinutes_4_nameOfFile",
    "dateHoursMinutes_1_nameOfFile",
    "dateHoursMinutes_3_nameOfFile",
    "dateHoursMinutes_2_nameOfFile"
};

char[] sep = new char[1] { '_' };
string[] sorted = _myFiles
    .OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(sep)[1]))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: nice answer sir never have thought of it

Comment: If your file format is strict enough that it will always have the character _ as the first instance prior to your order index that you are interested in this will work very nicely

Comment: I think index should be ordered by int rather than string. So that it would be 1,2,3,10 rather than 1,10,2,3

Comment: @Mark: Good catch. I modified the solution slightly by converting the string to an int.

Comment: and what if I have this format "\\Programs\\Drop_99\\recepes\\CLF\\20180626113520_2_WAVES.dat" ?

Comment: What index do you want to sort by? 99 or 2? This is not the format you mentioned in your question. Obviously the solution will differ depending on your actual data (filenames).

Comment: the index i want to sort by is 2

Comment: @sebba23: Just replace the index 1 by 2 then; `OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(sep)[2]))`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Substring` of `_index_` from main string to do so

```
Lst<string> fileNames = new List<string>();

var SortedFiles = FileNames.OrderBy(x => Decimal.Parse(path.Substring(path.IndexOf("_") + 1, path.Substring(path.IndexOf("_") + 1).IndexOf("_"))).ToList();
```

**Edit**: to sort file name such as `\\Programs\\Drop_99\\recepes\\CLF\\20180626113520_2_WAVES.dat`
use [`Path.GetFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Solution using below answer as ref.

```
 var sampl12836 = xspli.OrderBy(ele =>
 {
    var path = Path.GetFileName(ele);
    return Decimal.Parse(path.Split('_')[1]); 
 }).ToList();
```

Solution using my answer:-

```
var sorted = FileNames.OrderBy(ele =>
{
    var path = Path.GetFileName(ele);
    int firstIndex = path.IndexOf("_");
    return Decimal.Parse(path.Substring(path.IndexOf("_") + 1, path.Substring(firstIndex + 1).IndexOf("_"))); 
}).ToList();
```

Comment: and what if I have this format "\\Programs\\Drop_99\\recepes\\CLF\\20180626113520_2_WAVES.dat" ?