# Sort List<T> Multiple properties alphabetically and numerically

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following list with 3 columns. Column 3 is of type string, when trying to identify if it is an integer

```
Col1    Col2    Col3

0000    Item0   1
0000    Item0   10
0000    Item0   11
0000    Item0   12
0000    Item0   2
0000    Item0   3

0000    Item1   P1
0000    Item1   P10
0000    Item1   P11
0000    Item1   P12
0000    Item1   P2
0000    Item1   P3
```

when i try to sort it as follows, the last column is not sorted by field type

```
var orderedCustomers = Object.OrderBy(c => c.Col1).ThenBy(c => c.Col2).ThenBy(d => d.Col3);
```

Has anyone been through something similar, I want column 3 to be sorted asc but first numerically?

the result I am looking for is:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3

0000    Item0   1
0000    Item0   2
0000    Item0   3
0000    Item0   10
0000    Item0   11
0000    Item0   12

0000    Item1   P1
0000    Item1   P2
0000    Item1   P3
0000    Item1   P10
0000    Item1   P11
0000    Item1   P12
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting List<String> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716831/sorting-liststring-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The usual trick: `.ThenBy(d => d.Col3.Length).ThenBy(d => d.Col3)`, will work if within Col1 and Col2 the prefixes are equal-lenght.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a few helper methods to split and extract data from `Col3`.

- First we take the **non-numeric prefix** (or "" if there isn't any) and sort by that.
- Then we take the **numeric suffix**, convert it to an int value and sort by that as well. (I'm using `int.MaxValue` if there is no numeric suffix, you could use 0 or -1 if that suits you better)

```
var orderedCustomers = Object
   .OrderBy(c => c.Col1)
   .ThenBy(c => c.Col2)
   .ThenBy(d => TxtPart(d.Col3))
   .ThenBy(d => NumPart(d.Col3));

// Helper methods

public static string TxtPart(string s) => Regex.Match(s, @"^[^0-9]*").Value;

public static int NumPart(string s) => int.TryParse(Regex.Match(s, @"[0-9]*$").Value, out int v) ? v : int.MaxValue;
```

See this Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bfVTSr

Output:

```
0000, Item0, 1
0000, Item0, 2
0000, Item0, 3
0000, Item0, 10
0000, Item0, 11
0000, Item0, 12
0000, Item1, P1
0000, Item1, P2
0000, Item1, P3
0000, Item1, P10
0000, Item1, P11
0000, Item1, P12
```

Comment: The helper method NumPart, how would the function be if it were in .net5?

Comment: My code works (tested) from .NET Core 3 (which comes with C# 8) and up, so that includes .NET 5 (C# 9). If you mean the ancient and almost obsolete .NET Framework (C# 6 or below), then you'll need to put the declaration of `v` outside of the `int.TryParse` call, as follows, using a regular function body: `public static int NumPart(string s) { int v; return int.TryParse(Regex.Match(s, @"[0-9]*$").Value, out v) ? v : int.MaxValue; }`